# I can't connect to MySQL from EC2 while I can from localhost

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services

I am developing the backend of an application using ASP.NET and while I am in Visual Studio and testing the endpoints using a MySQL from Amazon it works fine. However when I upload the code at an EC2 instance and trying to test the same endpoints I got an error.

```
{
    "Message":"An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.",
    "ExceptionType":"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException",
    "StackTrace":" at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() 
        at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) 
        at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
        at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() 
        at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
        at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() 
        at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
}
```

The MySQL is an RDS and there is a Security Group attached to the EC2 which allows port 3306

Any ideas why this is happening ?

Comment: Where is your MySQL server running (RDS or EC2)? Does it have a Security Group Attached to it? Does your EC2 machine have a Security Group attach to it?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: _"which allows port 3306"_ - from _where_ does it allow it?

Comment: Inbound connection. The security group is attached to the EC2 and the RDS instance.

Comment: Yes, but inbound connection from _where_?  eg `0.0.0.0/0` (ie everywhere), or your specific IP address/range, or another security group etc etc

Comment: from the Private IP of the EC2 instance added to the end /32 (x.x.x.x/32) I have also tried /0 at the end

Comment: Have you allowed port in windows firewall ?

Comment: @KushVyas isn't what security groups doing actually ?

Comment: Yes but if it's windows instance , Port has to be open in firewall too or else even if security group allows it , it won't connect.

Comment: @KushVyas still it doesn't seem to work :( I put an exception in both inbound and outbound but nothing

Comment: Are your EC2 instance and RDS within the same VPC / subnet?  Can they actually route to each other?  There's a lot of things at play that could be wrong here to be honest.

Comment: @JamesThorpe The EC2 and the RDS are under the same VPC but I am not sure if they are on the same subnet. They should be on the same subnet? I haven't touch the route table